# How to programatically deploy to Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, shell, deployment, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

### The problem

I have configured a project that currently is possible to deploy to Firebase Hosting multi sites by using the Firebase CLI.

The problem is that currently I am doing this manually. And I want to programatically do this, and if possible, using NodeJS.

#### The steps of my system:

- User uploads a .zip file with a index.html
- I extract and check the .zip file with NodeJS
- I deploy the files to Firebase Hosting

#### Currently I am doing like this:

1. First create the site page with, where game-project-id-unique should be unique:

`firebase hosting:sites:create game-project-id-unique`

2. Then, add the target/project ID linked to the game, where game-id is defined by us:

`firebase target:apply hosting game-id game-project-id-unique`

3. Add to the firebase.json the configuration of the file (array):

```json
 {
      "target": "game-id",
      "public": "games/game-id",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
 }
```

4. Then, to publish:

`firebase deploy --only hosting`

#### Possible solutions?

I have researched here, I have found out that is possible to use the [API-DEPLOY](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy#access-token) or the [CLOUD BUILD](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#yaml_1), but this is not enough to guide me into the programatically approach, without the need of a human in-between.

Is there a way of doing this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly just write a script that invokes the CLI.  This is very common.

You can also use the [Firebase Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest), but in my opinion that is going to be a lot more work.

Comment: Makes sense! I think what's is missing for me is that after having that script, how could I make it run programatically?
Where should I deploy it to have the game files in a folder, for example?
But maybe this is a part of another problem, not firebase related anymore xD
Thank you!